# Operate a two-dimensional array, but it cannot be compiled

Tags: array

I want to operate a **two-dimensional array**(list), use the FindFit function, do linear simulation, and find the difference between the simulated value and the original value, but it cannot be compiled.

Does anyone know why?

Code like this:

```
    Unprotect["`*"];
    ClearAll["`*"]
    
    tbl = {{26, 20}, {18, 24}, {13, 34}, {10, 38}, {4, 50}, {-1, 64}};
    
    len_tbl = Length[tbl];
    f[x_] := k  x + b;
    fit = FindFit[tbl, f[x], {k, b}, x];
    g[x_] := f[x] /. fit;
    
    tbl_fit = Table[{tbl[[i]][[1]], g[tbl[[i]][[1]]]}, {i, 1, len_tbl}]
    (*tbl_fit=Table[g[tbl[[i]][[1]]],{i,1,len_tbl}]*)
    
    tbl_diff = Table[tbl_fit[[i]][[2]] - tbl[[i]][[2]], {i, 1, len_tbl}]
```

**The error is:**

Set::write: Tag List in len:Blank[{{26,20},{18,24},{13,34},{10,38},{4,50},{-1,64}}] is Protected.

Table::iterb: Iterator {i,1,len:Blank[{{26,20},{18,24},{13,34},{10,38},{4,50},{-1,64}}]} does not have appropriate bounds.

Set::write: Tag List in tbl:Blank[{k->-1.64773,b->57.5568}] is Protected.
Rule::rhs: Pattern tbl_fit appears on the right-hand side of rule tbl_diff->Table[tbl_fit[[i]][[2]]-tbl[[i]][[2]],{i,1,len:Blank[{{26,20},{18,24},{13,34},{10,38},{4,50},{-1,64}}]}].

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Underscore means [Blank](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) in the Wolfram Language. Remove it from the variable names and rerun. Also I cannot think of a good reason to use `Unprotect`. That amounts to rewriting the behavior governing the language tokens, if invoked.

Comment: However,there is no Blank or space char in the  variable's  definition

Comment: If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: The underscore character is not allowed in variable names.  `len_tbl`, `tbl_fit` and `tbl_diff` are not valid variable names.